# how can I change the color of boxes all at same time per run and not just one by one?

Tags: python, graphics

Here's the code. I'm essentially trying to do a game of life. But my trouble is changing one by one the boxes instead of all the cells at the time per run. How can I do that?

```
import graphics
import random
import numpy as np
import board_function

#numb of boxes per axis
x_scale=4
y_scale=4

#scale of the pantalladow
scale=50

#scale of each axis
tamaño_pantalla_x=x_scale*scale
tamaño_pantalla_y=y_scale*scale

#numb of alive cells at the start of the game
alive_starting_cells=4

#shows the board
pantalla=graphics.GraphWin("Juego de la Vida", tamaño_pantalla_x, tamaño_pantalla_y)

#arrays of each cell in the window
cells=[]

mapping={}

#iterates over each box
#over the x axis from scale to screen size in intervals of width: scale
for x in range (scale, tamaño_pantalla_x+1, scale):
    #over the y axis from scale to screen size in intervals of height: scale
    for y in range (scale, tamaño_pantalla_y+1, scale):

        c1=graphics.Point(x-scale, y-scale) # upper left corner
        c2= graphics.Point(x, y)            # lower right corner


        #creates object to represent each cell
        cell=graphics.Rectangle (c1, c2)

        #draws individually each cell on screen
        cell.draw(pantalla)

        #saves each cell in an array and matrix
        cells.append(cell)

        center= cell.getCenter()
        center_x= center.getX()
        center_y =center.getY()

        mapping[(center_x, center_y)]=(int((x-scale)/scale), int((y-scale)/scale), 0)

while alive_starting_cells >0:

    #get coordinate of the clic
    clic=pantalla.getMouse()
    clic_x =clic.getX()
    clic_y= clic.getY()

    color= graphics.color_rgb(0, 0, 250)

    #iterates over each cell to see wether it was clicked or not
    for i in range (0, len(cells)):

        #get coordinate of each cell
        center= cells[i].getCenter()
        center_x= center.getX()
        center_y =center.getY()

        #if both coordinates (x, y) are inside the cell, it was hitted
        #distancia entre centro y donde se hizo el clic debe ser menor o igual a la mitad de su altura o ancho
        #solo si cumple ambas condiciones esa celda fue seleccionada
        if abs(center_x-clic_x)<scale/2: 
            if abs(center_y - clic_y)<scale/2:
                #cambio color del objeto celda
                cells[i].setFill(color)

                (x, y, state)=mapping[(center_x, center_y)]
                print (x,y, state)
                mapping[(center_x, center_y)]= (x, y, 1)

                #reduzco el numero de celdas que faltan por asignar
                alive_starting_cells-=1

print (mapping)

index=0
T=0

while(T<20):

    for ind_x in range (x_scale):
        for ind_y in range (y_scale):
            x=(2*ind_x+1)*scale/2
            y=(2*ind_y+1)*scale/2
            indx, indy, state=mapping[(x,y)]
            mapping[(x,y)]=board_function.revisar_vecinos(x, y , state, mapping, scale, tamaño_pantalla_x, tamaño_pantalla_y)

    for ind_x in range (x_scale):
        for ind_y in range (y_scale):
            x=(2*ind_x+1)*scale/2
            y=(2*ind_y+1)*scale/2 
            if mapping[(x,y)][2]==1:
                cells[index].setFill(color)
                print('got here')
            elif mapping[(x,y)][2]==0:
                cells[index].setFill('white')
            index+=1

    T+=1
    index=0
print ('/n')
print(mapping)
```

This is the part that has to be changed. Because it changes each cell in the iteration instead of changing all the cells that need to changed per run at the same time.

```
for ind_x in range (x_scale):
            for ind_y in range (y_scale):
                x=(2*ind_x+1)*scale/2
                y=(2*ind_y+1)*scale/2 
                if mapping[(x,y)][2]==1:
                    cells[index].setFill(color)
                    print('got here')
                elif mapping[(x,y)][2]==0:
                    cells[index].setFill('white')
                index+=1
```

If you want to know 'revisar_vecinos' function I can also put it in here.

Comment: Use a graphics library that supports blitting, such as PyGame.

Comment: I will have to rewrite the whole code...

Comment: Well, yes. That's why it's important to research if the engine will be sufficient for the requirements.